# connect symfony with sqlite

Tags: sqlite, symfony

Error:
[image: error]

my question may seems silly, but i don' t know to do that.

I created a symfony project and want to connect it to sqlite database.

Here is my doctrine config

I also set up the DATABASE_URL var.

However, when i want to generate migrations for  example, i get the error could not find the driver.

I precise i installed sqlite by downloading a zip file.

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'pdo_sqlite'
        server_version: '5.7'
        charset: utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8mb4
            collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

IF anyone knows how to do it, i would be very thankful :)

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the error you get and also the code line of the DATABASE_URL you are using on .env file?

Comment: DATABASE_URL=sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/test.db i updated with the error

Comment: I think missing sqlite exension, what os are you using? Windows (Xampp/Wamp) or Linux?

Comment: Well i use Windows but is wamp compulsory to to have this extension ? Can t i Just download it ?

Comment: Try to enable extension in wamp context menu, php extension -> php_sqlite3 and restart wamp

Comment: but just to understand a point... Having wamp is compulsory or can i use sqlite without it? i guess i can

Comment: You need this exension to use with symfony/doctrine

Comment: but i could install sqlite pdo without wamp right? it is just easier cause wamp comes with it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Before using sqlite in wamp, you should enable exension php_sqlite3.

Enable extension in wamp context menu, php extension -> php_sqlite3 and restart wamp

Answer (score -1):

Either your driver isn't installed properly, run php -m to see if it appears in the list or you need to restart your web server (even if it's the embedded php-symfony web server)